# Scipy.optimize: parsing error occurs when maxiter is a large integer

Tags: python, scipy, integer

I am implementing a shooting method type problem and i used scipy.optimize.bisect from the scipy module.To achieve higher precision i wanted to go to large iteration numbers, but frequently got the error "unable to parse arguments".

It appears that the scipy function is unable to parse 2147483648=2^31 .
This has to be due to the fact that those large integers are stored as 64 bit instead of 32 bit numbers, but there must be a reason to circumvent this, right? is there anything i can do to have scipy accept large integers?

It seems unlikely that scipy would just straight up breaks down at those iteration numbers.
Help is appreciated!

code example:

```
#maxN=int(2**31)
maxN=int(2**31-1)
A=0
B=1
scipy.optimize.bisect(lambda x: x**2, a, b,maxiter=maxN)
```

If I set maxN to a number smaller than 2^31 everything works, but anything bigger than that leads to the error described above.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimial reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise, it's hard to help.

Comment: thanks @joni , I added the example

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `scipy.optimize.bisect` calls the [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.c) C function with signature:

```c
double 
bisect(callback_type f, double xa, double xb, double xtol, double rtol,
       int iter, void *func_data, scipy_zeros_info *solver_stats)
```

and typedefs

```c
typedef struct {
    int funcalls;
    int iterations;
    int error_num;
} scipy_zeros_info;

typedef double (*callback_type)(double, void*);
typedef double (*solver_type)(callback_type, double, double, double, double,
                              int, void *, scipy_zeros_info*);
```

where `iter` is the maximal number of allowed iterations. Since a `int` is exactly 32 bits (4 bytes) in size on most platforms, you can't pass a value larger than 2^31-1 as you already observed.

However, you can easily write your own `bisect` function with [Cython](https://cython.org/). You only need to change the function signatures, i.e. the type of `iter`, `iterations` and the loop variable `i` to `long long`.

Comment: Thank you. So you are saying I can simply take the C function, make the corrections you mentioned and then save it to somewhere to replace it in my version of the scipy package? I can't find the C-function in the package folder, can you tell me how I find the file where it is defined?

Comment: You can't find it, because it is compiled to a CPython extension module. So you either need to make your changes in the scipy source code (see github) and build scipy from source or you implement your own `bisect` function with cython.

Comment: okay, thank you. I really appreciate the effort :).